# Updating Mongoose model in catch block?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to update a model property in catch block for example

```
try {
 await model.status = 'success'
 await model.save()
} catch(err) {
 await model.status = 'failure'
 await model.save()
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far @justrying?

Comment: What's the issue?